# Bigraded Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

A bigraded $R$-module is defined (e.g. in McCleary's User's guide to spectral sequences) as a family of $R$-Modules indexed over tuples of integers ($\mathbb{Z}^2$).

My question:

Is this family an $R$-module again and how? (At least it is called a module...)
[My thoughts on this are that one takes the component-wise module structure, i.e. the product].

If my thoughts are right, why do we call it not just a product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not naturally a module: it is naturally a functor from a discrete category (the category whose objects are $\mathbb{Z}^2$, with no nontrivial morphisms) to modules. There are two natural ways to turn it into a module, one by taking the direct sum, and one by taking the direct product. When you say "family" you are reserving the right to do either or neither of these things depending on what ends up being useful later.

One sense in which a graded $R$-module is an $R$-module is that it is an $R$-module in graded abelian groups: that is, it is a graded abelian group on which $R$ acts by graded maps.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The term "family" indicates that the author is not, at the moment, interested in creating a unified algebraic structure with this construction alone. The purpose of the construction will likely become clear as you read on; in and of itself it is not particularly interesting, and there is no obvious natural way to turn this object into an $R$-module.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue!